# What is the way to preserve web user control to postback whole webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms, autopostback, webusercontrol

In my ASP.NET web project, i am using a web user control in a web form to generate insert/update/delete operations for the data in the web form.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="ctlUcusUpdatePanel">

    <ContentTemplate>

        <uc1:UcusBilgileriEditor runat="server" ID="ctlUcusBilgileriEditor" />

        <%-- Here I have a grid to display data--%>

    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is my user control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ctlEditorUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ctlEditorContentPanel" Visible="false">

            <div class="panel panel-primary" id="ctlUcusBilgiModal" style="position: relative; top: auto; left: auto; right: auto; margin: 0 auto 20px; z-index: 1; width: 100%; display: none">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <hzg:HZGLiteral runat="server" ID="ctlModalTitle"></hzg:HZGLiteral>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 20px 20px 2px 2px;">
                    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab">Genel</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#other" data-toggle="tab">Uçuş Detayları</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="#notes" data-toggle="tab">Açıklamalar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class=tab-content>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
                                <label class="control-label" for="<%= ctlFlightMoveType.ClientID %>">
                                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ctlFLightMoveLiteral" meta:resourcekey="ctlFlightMoveTypeLiteral" />
                                </label>
                                <hzg:HZGRadioButtonList ID="ctlFlightMoveType"
                                    AutoPostBack="true"
                                    CellPadding="3"
                                    RepeatColumns="5"
                                    RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                                    TextAlign="Right"
                                    runat="server"
                                    DataValueField="INISMI"
                                    EnumType="HZG.Core.Model.Enums.FlightMove"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ctlFlightMoveType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </hzg:HZGRadioButtonList>

                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer" style="text-align: right">
                    <hzg:HZGButton ID="ctlSaveButton" runat="server" ButtonDesign="success" ButtonSize="small" Text="Kaydet" OnClick="ctlSaveButton_Click" meta:resourcekey="ctlSaveButton" RolePermission="Admin,PowerUser,User" />
                    <hzg:HZGButton ID="ctlDeleteButton" runat="server" ButtonDesign="danger" ButtonSize="small" Text="Delete" OnClick="ctlDelete_Click" meta:resourcekey="ctlDeleteButton" OnClientClick='<%$ Resources:GlobalResource, AreYouSure%>' RolePermission="Admin,PowerUser,User" />
                    <hzg:HZGButton ID="ctlCloseButton" runat="server" ButtonDesign="primary" ButtonSize="small" Text="İptal" OnClick="ctlCloseButton_Click" meta:resourcekey="ctlCloseButton" />
                </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I click on a radiobutton in my RadiButtonList, ctlFlightMoveType_SelectedIndexChanged event is triggered; and when this happens, i want only my user control to postback but my web form postback and the user control is closed.

I dont want the webform to postback, i want only user control. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please, read the [AJAX overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you can also read up about [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Using `UpdatePanel` you can achieve the feature described in your question.

Comment: I use update panel. I will check out the links you give, thank you. <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ctlEditorUpdatePanel" runat="server">

Comment: I couldn't find any solution to my problem. Is there anyone who can give an idea?

Answer (score 0):

On your user control update panel make sure you have childrenastriggers=true. And on the script manager declaration (in your main page) make sure you have enablepartialupdates selected.

If it's still forcing a full post back, chances are you have some iffy html somewhere on the page.